# log file not getting created via log4j2

Tags: servlets, web-applications, log4j2

I have a simple servlet application and trying to implement `log4j2` in my web application
The log4j2 jars are - `log4j-api-2.17.1.jar` / `log4j-core-2.17.1.jar`, servlet application 3.1,
Tomcat 8.5
My `log4j2.properties` file reside in `WEB-INF/classes/resources/log4j2.properties`

[image]

In my tomcat root directory, I have a folder Log4j2 where log file needs to be created
Logs are getting printed in the console but log file is not getting created in the Log4j2 directory.
As per my observation, log4j2.properties is being read by the application since I have changed the pattern for console and it gets reflected, but I am not able to debug why log file is not getting created.
I will be grateful if some one can help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The `${catalina.home}` placeholder resolves to a property in the `log4j2.properties` file. Since you don't define it, it resolves to literally "${catalina.home}" in the current working directory of the server.

Use `${sys:catalina.home}` instead to resolve the Java system property (cf. [lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html).